# iOS Bluetooth Device connect/disconnect from Settings

Tags: ios, bluetooth, settings

If i have already connected bluetooth device from Settings screen and my application is running, Suddenly i go to setting screen and disconnect that bluetooth device but still bluetooth switch is on. So is it any way or method, by using that we can identify that device is connected or disconnected from settings?

Comment: Looks like you did not include your entire question. Try to be clearer and to the point.

Comment: If you go to Settings/Bluetooth it will tell you what devices are connected.  I'm confused about what you are asking?